# Can I legally work remotely for a company in UK from India?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, india, contractor

I am currently working full-time for a company in India. I got a chance to work in  a contractor position remotely for another company in UK. They are willing to pay me to my UK bank account only. So, I am planning to work for both companies.

Few points I would like to clarify:

1. I do not currently hold any kind of work permit in UK nor I have
   British passport. I am an Indian citizen. I previously worked in UK
   with a valid work permit which is expired now.
2. Since, I previously worked in UK, I still have my UK bank account open. And I am planning to give this account details for my UK contractor position salary.

My question is:
Firstly, Is this legal? If yes, then do I need to pay taxes in UK or India?

Answer (score 3):

> So, I am planning to work for both companies.

Check the Appointment letter of your current employer. You may be forbidden to work with other employer even as contractor, these maybe some process to be followed even if they allow you in writing.

> Is this legal?

If the agreement with the UK company is drafted as Independent Contract, there are no issues. It is perfectly legal.

> do I need to pay taxes in UK or India?

You would definitely be required to pay taxes in India on this. Whether there would be UK taxes depends on how your contract with the UK company is worded. Ensure that taxes if any in UK will be paid by the UK company and you get the agreed amount.

In Indian IT returns you would have to paid Advance Tax every quarter and while filing returns show this as income from other source.